# Filter in Excel 2016 using the same date range on multiple columns

Tags: filter

I'm trying to display rows when any of the columns B, C, D, E, or F has a date no more than 10 days old.  It doesn't matter if any of the other columns have dates more than 10 days old.

I tried advanced filters and filter on filter but if there is a date in any of the columns more than 10 days old it won't display the row.

Any help is appreciated.

```
  A        B          C           D            E           F
```

1   Item    Submitted   to Ann      to Joe      from Ann    from Joe
2   381-02  07/06/18    07/06/18    07/24/18
3   480-00  06/29/18    06/29/18    07/24/18    07/24/18    07/25/18
4   483-00  07/02/18    07/03/18
5   490-00  07/06/18    07/07/18    07/24/18    07/25/18    07/25/18
6   491-00  07/06/18    07/07/18    07/24/18
7   492-00  07/06/18    07/07/18
8   493-00  07/10/18    07/10/18                07/25/18    07/26/18

```
    Display the row if any date in these columns (D-H)              
     is greater than 10 day from today.
```

Comment: what func/formula you are using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to do this without vba and only use ecxel function then you need to make a nested if  (in a new column)  and use the OR operator. So in the end if any of the cells in the rows is greater then 10 days write 1 if false write 0

And just sort your new column by 1